# Change magento cart empty page layout

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I just want to change the page layout of magento cart (Only when empty!). I've tested it with the following code in (checkout.xml and local.xml) but nothing happened.

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action >
```

Magento 1.7 - Cache disabled - live Site

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this to your theme's layout/local.xml:

```
 <checkout_cart_index>
   <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
 </checkout_cart_index>
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work. I've already tested this. Thank you anyway